# How to do insertion sort with a decreasing range

Tags: python, sorting

What am I suppose to add on a decreasing range for insertion sort to make it work because the first 2 number on the list does not sort properly

```
def insertion_sort(list):    
     for index in range(len(list)-1,0,-1):    
       current_value = list[index]         
       position = index 

       while position > 0 and list[position - 1] > current_value:             
          list[position] = list[position - 1]           
          position = position - 1 

       list[position] = current_value 

list = [87,95,6,18,25,42,1,78,61]
insertion_sort(list) 
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
def insertionSort(list):       
    for j in xrange(1,len(list)):
        valToInsert = list[j]
        i = j-1
        while 0 <= i and valToInsert>list[i]:
            list[i+1] = list[i]
            i -= 1
        list[i+1] = valToInsert
    return list

list = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
insertionSort(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: I need the xrange to be decending like (len(list)-1,0,-1)

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: the output should be the same as the answer you gave which is in ascending order but i need the range to be that ^

Comment: try this range(1,len(list))

Comment: i need the range to be (len(list),0,-1) for my research question. I cannot change the range